# Magento move upsell products to footer

Tags: magento

Is it possible to move the Magento upsell products from the default content column to, in this case, the footer?

I tried to change the reference of the product.info.upsell block from content to footer but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to move the call to `$this->getChildHtml('layoutname')` to the place where you want it to go.

Comment: That is the solution! Except for changing the reference I also had to move `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>` to footer.phtml.